# Advantage of the Monte Carlo method over a regular periodic sampling

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, monte-carlo

I am unclear on when to use the Monte Carlo random sampling method for algorithm design. The classic example that I keep seeing is using random points within some bounding rectangle to determine the area of some irregular figure. Wouldn't a regular periodic sampling provide more repeatable results for this application then using the Monte Carlo (random sampling) method?

Comment: The question, as asked, is too broad: there are whole books written on this kind of thing. If you were looking for more than what was given in Yuval's answer, please edit your question to make it more specific so we can re-open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a fixed seed then Monte Carlo is also repeatable. Monte Carlo sampling has the advantage that the expected number of points inside your figure is proportional to the area, which is not necessarily the case for a grid — you can come up with a contrived figure in which the grid is off by a lot, whereas random points are impossible to "fool" this way.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for your answer.